# Python / Shapely Touching Contains

Tags: python, shapely

I'm trying to write an algorithm, that can check if a polygon is within another, but they share a border.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
poly = Polygon(((0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0)))
poly2 = Polygon(((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)))
# poly.contains(poly2) will return False
```

Is there a other way than checking if at least one point from poly2 is within poly and they don't cross (points within and outside poly)?

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
poly = Polygon(((0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0)))
poly2 = Polygon(((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)))
poly3 = Polygon(((0, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 0)))
# desired result poly.func(poly2) == True poly.func(poly3) == False
```

Comment: Have you tried some of Shapely's other functions, like `intersects`? `contains` appears to only be true if `poly2` is in the _interior_ of `poly`, not along the border.

Comment: To my knowledge intersects would return True for poly.intersects(poly2) and poly2.intersects(poly). For my use the second one should be False

Comment: what constitutes crossing?

Comment: In Shapely 1.6.4 the first code returns `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can examine detailed spatial relationships using the [**DE-9IM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) model, which "intersects", "contains", etc., are based on. This data can be obtained from [`relate`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#de-9im-relationships):

```
A = poly
B = poly2
rel = A.relate(B)
print(rel)  # 212F11FF2
```

And as viewed in JTS TestBuilder:
[image: DE-9IM]

So to find "at least one point from poly2 is within poly and they don't cross (points within and outside poly)" and if they "share a border", this is spatial-predicate-speak this requires all conditions to be true:

- I(A) ∩ I(B) = 2 or `rel[0] == '2'` to find if at least one point from B is within A resulting with an areal intersection
- B(A) ∩ B(B) = {0, 1} or `rel[5] in '01'` to see if the two share a border (point or line)
- E(A) ∩ I(B) = F or `rel[6] == 'F'` to find if B don't cross outside A

So, make your own spatial predicate:

```
def my_criteria(A, B):
    rel = A.relate(B)
    return rel[0] == '2' and rel[5] in '01' and rel[6] == 'F'

my_criteria(poly, poly2)  # True
my_criteria(poly2, poly)  # False
```